# Realm - how to make sure db won't be deleted

Tags: ios, macos, realm

I've added some fields to my Realm db (at my iOS/ OSX apps), and added migration when initiating Realm. I'm using the default configuration.
Now I want to be sure that:

1. the database won't be deleted when the user updates the app
   (From my tests it's seems ok, but I want to be sure)
2. less important, but what happens when I give someone a beta version (with the updated fields), and after a while he removes it, and download from the store the previous version (without the newer fields) - I saw that all his db has been deleted :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Realm database will never delete itself unless you tell it to!

There's a setting, which should IMO only be used in development or for *truly* ephemeral caches, called [`Realm.Configuration.deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded`](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/Realm/Configuration.html#/s:vVC10RealmSwift5Realm13Configuration28deleteRealmIfMigrationNeededSb), but if you never explicitly set that to `true`, Realm will throw a runtime exception in case of missing migration.

You can also delete Realm files on disk using something like `NSFileManager` or equivalent POSIX APIs, but you'd know when you do that, since that's entirely under your control.

> less important, but what happens when I give someone a beta version (with the updated fields), and after a while he removes it, and download from the store the previous version (without the newer fields) - I saw that all his db has been deleted :(

This can happen if you override the default location where the Realm is stored. By default, it's stored in the Documents directory on iOS, meaning that it will be backed up via iTunes and iCloud and should be available again after recovering from a backup. If you set the Realm location to a location that iOS doesn't back up, or if your user doesn't back up their device, then you're on your own.

Comment: Thanks! but just to make sure - all of this is valid for OSX as well?

Comment: Yes. All Realm APIs work on all Apple platforms, unless otherwise noted (really just no interprocess support on tvOS, and no encryption on watchOS).